# C# Windows Forms Link two buttons by line

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, windows-forms-designer

Hay, I have two buttons (image 1), and i would like to link this buttons by line. I thought about drawing line by Class Graphics and Pen, but I tried this and it doesn't work.

[image: image1]

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var lineBegin = new Point(button1.Left + button1.Width - 1, button1.Top + button1.Height / 2);
            var lineEnd = new Point(button2.Left, button2.Top + button2.Height / 2);

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Maroon, lineBegin, lineEnd);
        }
```

Comment: Assuming both buttons were in the same CONTAINER (the form, maybe?...but possibly something else), you'd handle the `Paint()` event of that container and draw the line using the supplied `e.Graphics` from the parameters of that event. Show you attempt that didn't work and we can posssibly help you fix it.

Comment: `private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var lineBegin = new Point(button1.Left + button1.Width - 1, button1.Top + button1.Height / 2);
            var lineEnd = new Point(button2.Left, button2.Top + button2.Height / 2);

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Maroon, lineBegin, lineEnd);
        }`

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works, but I can move my buttons while program is running, so I think it must every second check and drawline. How can I do this?

Comment: EDIT your original post above and ADD your code there so it can be formatted properly and people can read it.

Comment: Just issue a `this.Invalidate()` whenever the buttons are moved and the line should automatically redraw itself...

Comment: @Adrian do not post code in the comments. [edit] your question to add details, or add an answer to your own question.

Comment: Where must I paste `this.Invalidate`? In Button Move Function or in Form1_Paint?

Comment: In whatever code triggers each time one of the buttons is moved.

Comment: Show your CODE so we can help you fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

[image: pic]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            Pens.Blue,
            button1.Right + 2,
            button1.Top + button1.Height / 2,
            button2.Left - 2,
            button2.Top + button2.Height / 2);
    }
}
```